# Adding Keyword in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add a keyword in eclipse for some common statements i type in my program.
e.g I don't want to type System.out.println again and again in my code. So i want to have some keyword which can do the job quickly. Can anyone please help?

Comment: It's called Template, not KEYWORD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates

Answer (score 3):

Type "SYSO" (any case) Then Ctrl + Space and it gets auto completed as Sysout.
Tyoe SYSE for error and SYS for all System.* options

Answer (score 2):

By default in Eclipse you can type sysout and use ctrl + space to autocomplete to System.out.println().

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [cheatsheet of the currently available shortcuts](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-cheatsheet/downloads/list) in Eclipse from Google Code.

Also you might want to read the [Eclipse Wiki FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action?) on creating shortcuts for more information on how to go about creating your keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

In your case , you can use type

> sysout for system.pur.println()

and type

> syserr for System.err.println(),

then click

> ctrl + space

. It would do a auto complete.

In case you want to edit any key bindings , go to,

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys.

There will be a UI with all the keys and it's bindings. Click on the command you would like to edit the keys. You already have huge set of commands, but not having key binding. Perhaps you would like to use one of those commands. Or you can copy the command and modify the key bindings according to your context using the when conditions. Open and play whatever you want. In case if your feel that you are goofing up, click restore defaults. And play again with those keys.

If you want list down all the short cuts , click

> ctrl + shift + l